# How to show Image In GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a live project in which I have to prepare an Admin interface. In this Admin Interface the Admin of the website can manipulate data and user images. Problem is that I am unable to show the image because I have saved image path in database in respect to associate  userid. I am also able to show data but I don't know how to show data so that the Admin can make changes upon it.

Comment: Why are you, `unable to show the image because I have saved image path in database in respect to associate userid`?    What data do you want the Admin to change?

Comment: Thanks Abe for view.I want to how full record of user.so that admin can modify any record and instead of userimagepath i want to show its image in Image control.

Answer (score 0):

To display the image you will probably need to make the directory that you are storing your images in a Virtual Directory in IIS.  Once you do this you should be able to create a URL based on the file name.  Example:

if your file path is `C:\UserImages\1234.jpg`

You will need to make UserImages a Virtual Directory, then in your code do something like this:

```
string baseImgUrl = "http://myServer/UserImages/";
FileInfo fi = //load with the file path C:\UserImages\1234.jpg;
img_myImageControl.ImageURL = baseImgUrl + fi.FileName;
```

haven't tested this, but it should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this to show the image in the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImageAddress") %>' alt='I am a user image' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Of course you'd have to modify things a bit (depending on how you have things saved in the database).